# Method of identifying plaintext files as scripts

Tags: language-agnostic, file-type

I am creating a filter for files coming onto a Unix machine. I only want to allow plain text files that do not look like scripts to pass through.

For checking plain text I am checking the executable bit of the file and using the -T file test from perl. (I understand this is not 100%, but it will catch the binary files I most want to avoid). I think this will be sufficient, but any suggestions are welcome.

My main question is in recognizing when a plain text file is a script. Every script I've ever written has started out with a `#!` line, so my first thought is to read in the file's first line and block any containing that. Are there common non-script plain text files that start with the `#!` line that I will flag with a false-positive?  Are there better/additional methods of identifying a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `file` command (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)) is for.  It recognizes much more than just the she-bang (`#!`), and can tell you what kind of script it is, if any.

Comment: I was unaware it went to such detail. Thank you.